# ListView Items Overlap for Small Icon view after application.enablevisualstyles() - C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I am working on C# Windows Application and I have enabled WindowsXP Theme by calling  `application.enablevisualstyles()`. There is a `ListView` in one of the forms and `Items` are constituted with `Text` and `Image`. Images for the `ListView` items are assigned through `ImageList`. I am using 16-bit images for Small View and 32-bit for Large View. List View Items can be viewed in Large, Small, List and Details.

The Issue we are facing is, ListView items alignment is going for toss for Small View, List and Details. Items are getting overlapped with each other.

I observed that this happens only for Small View followed by List and Details View. 
Issue will not appear if we remove `application.enablevisualstyles()` but we need Windows XP theme.

Attached image for reference. Here, ListView items are displayed in Small Icon View. If we look into this, Items alignment is not proper.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @defaultlocale - Screenshot is attached for your reference.

Comment: That is the way it is supposed to look.  You've got too much text, it doesn't fit.  Fixable by calling the listview's AutoResizeColumns() method to force the columns to get wider.  But it isn't exactly "small" anymore so maybe the view just isn't very useful.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, this is a migration project from VB 6 to C#. In VB 6, for the same listview, items are aligned properly for small icon view. why this different behaviour in C# ?